# Bootloader help

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I am new to Linux. I am sure if I searched enough I could figure this out but, I keep running into the same issue. I have just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I unfortunately have only one computer in working order in my household. My computer has three 500GB hard drives, and I have a different OS installed on each hard drive: Windows XP, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I am asking how do I load a boot menu screen immediately after POST automatically. I have found resources to do this from a Live USB, but I'm looking for an easy way to select my operating system from a boot menu.

Comment: It is not clear what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. One solution is to make the Ubuntu hard drive the boot drive. At first boot it may boot directly to Ubuntu. Once there open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and type `sudo update-grub` this will generate the boot menu with other OSs and you will see the choice at the next boot.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have installed bootloader at one of the drives, that is not by default first boot option. First please try to change boot order in bios, so that the HDD on which Ubuntu is installed is a first option. It might help.